# Standardising for RELU neural nets

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

Consider a one hidden layer neural net, with RELU activations. It seems that it is common practice in neural nets to standardise the weights such that they are distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,1/sqrt(d))$ where $d$ is the dimensionality of the data.

Suppose that I normalise the data before I send it into the net. The question is what are the best practices with normalising *the input data*. The main concern is considering that RELUs have zero gradient for negative values that the learning will stop, creating 'dead neurons'.

I have included the following plots with two different initialisations (`StandardScaler` and `MinMaxScaler` in scikit-learn speak). I realise that the histograms aren't conclusive but might be a start. Note especially how the variance is smaller for `MinMaxScaler`s. Also I know that the biases are there to push the negative values, but again a common initialisation for biases that I've seen is zero.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10000
D = 100
Dout = 20

# Gaussian intialisation (0 mean 1 standard deviation)
x = np.random.randn(N, D)
w = np.random.randn(D, Dout)*1/np.sqrt(Dout)
y = x.dot(w)

plt.hist(y.ravel(),100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# MinMaxScaler (values between 0 and 1)
x = np.random.rand(N, D)
y = x.dot(w)

plt.hist(y.ravel(),100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest RELU leaky in your case and some method to optimise learning rate with addition for saving computing[image: relu_leaky + derivatives].

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    def relu_leaky(x):
        return np.where(x>=0,x,x*0.1)        

    def relu_deriv(x):
        return np.where(x>0,1,0.1)

    X = np.arange(-10,10)
    y1 = relu_leaky(X)
    y2 = relu_deriv(y1)


    plt.plot(X,y1)
    plt.scatter(X,y2,c='red')
```